# Getting file path from uri on emulator

Tags: android, storage

I want to get file path from Uri for a video. The following method works fine when testing with a real device, however, it fails (returns null) when testing on emulator.

```
    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What is the correct way of getting file path from uri on emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following method works fine when testing with a real device

Only on the the device that you tried, and only for the app that you tried. Particularly on Android 4.4+, your approach will be unreliable. That is because [a `Uri` is not a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). On older versions of Android, for a `Uri` from the `MediaStore`, your approach might work.

Nowadays, do not attempt to get a file for a `Uri`. Consume the `Uri` as you are supposed to, using methods on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream`, the MIME type, etc.

> What is the correct way of getting file path from uri on emulator?

There is none. There does not have to be a file path associated with a `Uri`, let alone a path that your app is able to access using Java file I/O.

Comment: What if I need to get file path in order to store it in database and play the video associated with it? What would be the right approach in that case?

Comment: @Mantas: What you want is not going to generally work. On Android 4.4 and higher, you can [try `takePersistableUriPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to get durable rights, then save the `Uri` (in `String` form) in your database. But there is no requirement that the video still be there in the future, and there is no requirement that the `Uri` be valid for all that long, particularly prior to Android 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

As CommonsWare mentioned, an Uri is NOT a File. The general way to deal with Uri is to use an inputstream and save the content as a file (assuming that's what you are looking for). What i typically do is

1. get the metadata associated with the Uri (to get title / type of data / size)
2. get the content via an input stream to save it on the device as a file.

Take a look at the "Examine document metadata" and "get an inputstream" on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html